# How to get each component to display correct Children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've created Layout component which is macro page layout that consists of two sub-components: `BodyContent` and `RightPanel`. When `rightPanelOpen` prop is set to **true**, `BodyContent` takes 70% of viewport width and `RightPanel` takes 30% of width. If `rightPanelOpen` is set to **false** then `BodyContent` takes 100% width.
Problem I'm facing is regards to how each sub-component is displaying children prop. For `BodyContent`, I was expecting it to display "This is for Body content" and for `RightPanel`, I was expecting to see "Right Side Panel". But I see entire sentence "This is for Body content Right Side Panel" displayed on each sub-component. Not sure how I can dissect the children prop further from here. What am I doing wrong? https://codesandbox.io/s/layout-demo-ts-nsvceu?file=/src/App.tsx:845-906

App.tsx

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
import { RightPanel } from "./RightPanel";
import { BodyContent } from "./BodyContent";

export interface LayoutProps {
  rightPanelOpen?: boolean;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

export const Layout: React.FunctionComponent<LayoutProps> & {
  RightPanel: typeof RightPanel;
  BodyContent: typeof BodyContent;
} = function Layout({ rightPanelOpen = false, children }: LayoutProps) {
  const content = rightPanelOpen ? (
    <>
      <BodyContent sectioned={true}>{children}</BodyContent>
      <RightPanel>{children}</RightPanel>
    </>
  ) : (
    <BodyContent sectioned={false}>{children}</BodyContent>
  );

  return <div className="layout-flex">{content}</div>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Layout rightPanelOpen={true}>
      <Layout.BodyContent sectioned={true}>
        <h1> This is for </h1>
        <h2> Body content </h2>
      </Layout.BodyContent>
      <Layout.RightPanel>
        <h1>Right Side Panel</h1>
      </Layout.RightPanel>
    </Layout>
  );
}
Layout.RightPanel = RightPanel;
Layout.BodyContent = BodyContent;
```

BodyContent.tsx

```
import "./styles.css";

export interface BodyContentProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  sectioned?: boolean;
}

export function BodyContent({ children, sectioned = false }: BodyContentProps) {
  return (
    <div className={sectioned ? "bodyWidth-70" : "bodyWidth-100"}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

RightPanel.tsx

```
import "./styles.css";

export interface RightPanelProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

export function RightPanel({ children }: RightPanelProps) {
  return <div className="rightSideWidth">{children}</div>;
}
```

Comment: like this could work: https://codesandbox.io/s/layout-demo-ts-forked-2lfyts?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: I added a second version that allow to pass the Rightpanel down only if rightPanelOpen is true, if you prefer that (yeah i was having fun :D )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with two versions, the first take always both `BodyContent` and `RightPanel` as children:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { cloneElement, ReactElement } from "react";
import { RightPanel, RightPanelProps } from "./RightPanel";
import { BodyContent, BodyContentProps } from "./BodyContent";

export interface LayoutProps {
  rightPanelOpen?: boolean;
  children: [ReactElement<BodyContentProps>, ReactElement<RightPanelProps>];
}

export const Layout: React.FunctionComponent<LayoutProps> & {
  RightPanel: typeof RightPanel;
  BodyContent: typeof BodyContent;
} = function Layout({
  rightPanelOpen = false,
  children: [bodyContent, rightPanel]
}: LayoutProps) {
  const content = rightPanelOpen ? (
    <>
      {cloneElement(bodyContent, { sectioned: true })}
      {rightPanel}
    </>
  ) : (
    <>{bodyContent}</>
  );

  return <div className="layout-flex">{content}</div>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Layout rightPanelOpen={true}>
      <Layout.BodyContent>
        <h1> This is for </h1>
        <h2> Body content </h2>
      </Layout.BodyContent>
      <Layout.RightPanel>
        <h1>Right Side Panel</h1>
      </Layout.RightPanel>
    </Layout>
  );
}
Layout.RightPanel = RightPanel;
Layout.BodyContent = BodyContent;
```

The second version instead take `RightPanel` only if `rightPanelOpen` is `true`. I had to drop the props deconstructuring in the function paramenters because it seems to mess with discriminated unions (it should work fine in more recent version of typescript):

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { cloneElement, ReactElement } from "react";
import { RightPanel, RightPanelProps } from "./RightPanel";
import { BodyContent, BodyContentProps } from "./BodyContent";

export type LayoutProps =
  | {
      rightPanelOpen?: true;
      children: [ReactElement<BodyContentProps>, ReactElement<RightPanelProps>];
    }
  | {
      rightPanelOpen?: false;
      children: ReactElement<BodyContentProps>;
    };

export const Layout: React.FunctionComponent<LayoutProps> & {
  RightPanel: typeof RightPanel;
  BodyContent: typeof BodyContent;
} = function Layout(props: LayoutProps) {
  let content;
  if (props.rightPanelOpen) {
    const [bodyContent, rightPanel] = props.children;
    content = (
      <>
        {cloneElement(bodyContent, { sectioned: true })}
        {rightPanel}
      </>
    );
  } else {
    content = <>{props.children}</>;
  }

  return <div className="layout-flex">{content}</div>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Layout rightPanelOpen={true}>
      <Layout.BodyContent>
        <h1> This is for </h1>
        <h2> Body content </h2>
      </Layout.BodyContent>
      <Layout.RightPanel>
        <h1>Right Side Panel</h1>
      </Layout.RightPanel>
    </Layout>
  );
}
Layout.RightPanel = RightPanel;
Layout.BodyContent = BodyContent;
```

In both versions i tried to specify exactly the children the component expects. I also moved where `sectioned` is specified (based on `rightPanelOpen`)

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/layout-demo-ts-forked-2lfyts?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: I just have couple of questions. First, `children: [bodyContent, rightPanel]` does this destructing separate contents from BodyContent from contents from RightPanel? 
Second, what's the advantage of using cloneElement `{cloneElement(bodyContent, { sectioned: true })}` over my original way? `<BodyContent sectioned={true}>{children}</BodyContent>`

Comment: So, `children: [bodyContent, rightPanel]` is just a simple array deconstructuring. i'm assuming the first child in `BodyContent` and the second child is`RightPanel`. About the second part the advantage is that you don't have to manually pass `sectioned` down when `rightPanelOpen` is true (i assumed this was always the case), but it's done automatically.

Comment: In your first solution app.tsx, if I set `rightPanelOpen` to false and pass in only `Layout.BodyContent` only inside of `Layout`, I get "object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))" error. How can I fix this? I do like this solution as when I set `rightPanelOpen` to false, even when I pass `Layout.RightPanel`, it only display BodyContent.

Comment: The first solution assumes you alway pass both elements (even when `rightPanelOpen` is false) while the second solution accept `RigthPanel` ONLY when `rightPanelOpen` is true. I've added a third solution to the demo that is like the second solution but accept a `RighPanel` child even when `rightPanelOpen` is false and ignores it.

Comment: Thanks for this! Just wondering I notice you used discriminated unions with `type`. Can discriminated unions be used with `interface` as well or it has to be `type`?

Comment: I think it's one of the few cases where you have to use `type`